# Override the Focus event of an external page that loads in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an external page loading in an iframe and it seems to be getting focus, since the page scrolls (by itself) to that specific iframe.

Is there a way to override this?

Answer (score 0):

You can bring focus back to document

```
window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
     setTimeout(function() {
         if(document.activeElement === document.getElementById('frame_id')) {
             setTimeout(window.focus, 5);
         }
     }, 10);
});
```